# Likelihood ratio test statistic for Poisson GLM

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I consider data {$y_{ij}$} which is a rectangular table of counts, and that follows a Poisson distribution, $y_{ij}\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu_{ij})$. The mean value, $\mu_{ij}$ depends on a variable $x_{ij}$, which for each pair $(i,j)$ is known. As a model I have the following: $$\mu_{ij}=\alpha_i\beta_jx_{ij}^\gamma.$$ I have derived the log likelihood function as: $$\sum_i\sum_j(y_{ij}\log \mu_{ij}-\mu_{ij}-\log y_{ij}!).$$ Now I want to derive a large-sample type test statistic (e.g. likelihood ratio test statistic) for testing if $x_{ij}$ has influence on $\mu_{ij}$ . More specifically, however, this test statistic should be selected such that
it does not involve the MLE of $\gamma$.

Comment: In fact, $x_{ij}$  has influence on $μ_{ij}$ means $γ \ne 0$. How can test statistics does not involve  MLE of $γ$?

Comment: hm, that's true. I mean I basically want to construct the LR-test, but gets really big expressions that does'nt seem to be right.

Comment: Suppose your log likelihood function is correct (I did not verify), then replace $\mu_{ij}$ by $\alpha_i\beta_jX_{ij}^\gamma$, get MLE of $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$, get value of log likelihood function at the value of MLE of the parameters. Repeat it by fixing $\gamma = 0$. 2 times of the difference follows Chi square distribution with df =1. It is likelihood ratio test. But i did not think there is simpler way. Of course you may find the available software to finish these steps for you.